# What is the story of Maharishi Patanjali?

Tags: yoga-sutras, patanjali

He is the propagator of yoga and grammar.

Well known for his great works.

What was his life story ?

Answer (score 4):

Maharishi Patanjali was a saint who is believed to have lived some time during the 2nd century BCE.

> He was contemporary of Puṣyamitra Śuṅga (185 – 149 BCE : the founder and first ruler of the Shunga dynasty). He was the priest in the **Ashwamedha yajna** performed by Puṣyamitra Śuṅga.

He is known for his treatise on Yoga, entitled

> Patanjali Yoga Sutra

Tradition says that Patanjali was also the author of

> Mahaabhaashya (related to grammar)
>
> Charakapratisamskrtah (medical text)
>
> **Note:** There has been a considerable debate on these two.

Hence, Patanjali is believed as a saint

> who removed the impurities of the **mind** through Yoga, of **speech** through Grammar, and of the **body** through medicine.

More about Maharishi Patanjali can be found [here](http://artoflivingsblog.com/maharishi-patanjali/).

Comment: Maharishi Patanjali year of birth was around 1400 BC.