# Was Sage Patanjali the chief priest of king Pushyamitra Sunga?

Tags: history, yoga, yoga-sutras

I heard that he was. I also read somewhere (which I can't remember) that this information is mentioned in the Yoga Sutra itself. But I could not find it. It is also mentioned in this [post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/what-is-the-story-of-maharishi-patanjali) in Hinduism Stack Exchange. Though it does not have any reference.

By the way, in case someone does not know, Pushyamitra Sunga ended the Buddhist Maurya dynasty of Magadha. And He established the Hindu Kingdom and performed many Ashwamedha Yajna.